# Login failed for local DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET project which includes a local database. The connection string in web.config is this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MerchantConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Merchant.mdf; Integrated  Security=True" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I can open the DB in Sql Server 2012 Mgmt Studio with no problem using Windows Authentication, but in ASP.NET, I get Login Failed for the Windows user (the one that can open it in Mgmt Studio). Here's the Sql Datasource section on the Aspx page:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MerchantConnection  %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT [StateCode], [StateName] from [dbo.States] ORDER BY [StateCode]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: try to ignore integrated security parameter in your connection string. `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Merchant.mdf;`

Answer (score 1):

Have you started Management Studio as an admin?
Apart of that, you are referring -via asp.net- to a file, which could be an issue.
Usually, a database is accessed. 
Standard connection strings have worked for me all the time.
[hope that helps you](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

EDIT: perhaps you are missing InitialCatalog=DatabaseName; ? within your connstr

Comment: Mgmt Studio was not run as an Admin. I've used the direct file name before as part of an ASP.NET project with no problem at all. Just need to see where to look to diagnose.   **As it turns out, it was a simple problem: I did not have using System.Data.SqlClient; in my associated cs file.****

Comment: perhaps you are missing InitialCatalog=DatabaseName; ? within your connstr

Comment: I did not have that statement but it still worked just fine. The only problem was the missing Using statement.

Comment: @Ron If you have solved your own issue, please post an answer describing what fixed it and mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I needed to add using System.Data.SqlClient; in two cs files. Very easy to fix. The error was literally correct but there was no clue as to why.